# How to Add Visual Effects to a Video Using android 4.0

Tags: android, effect

How to Add Visual Effects to a Video Using android 4.0?
Android4.0 has package effect, it said could be used in video, but I didn't know how to use.

Comment: Hey Kallyena, Did you find solution of this problem?